# Wie beschreibt man das Futur mit der Vergangenheitsform?

Tags: verb, expression

Wenn man etwas, das man vorhatte, ausdrücken will oder eine in der Vergangenheit stattfindende Geschichte erzählt, kann diese Form in Englisch verwendet werden:

> I was going to go to the library.
>
> He was going to run away from home, before he was caught.

Ist die einzige richtig Übersetzung

> Ich wollte zur Bibliothek gehen.
>
> Er wollte von zu Hause weglaufen, bevor er gefangen wurde.

Für mich scheint das aber keine präzise Übersetzung zu sein.

Edit: Es ist mir gerade eingefallen, dass man `vorhaben` benutzen kann

> Ich hatte es vor, zur Bibliothek zu gehen
>
> Er hatte es vor, von zu Hause wegzulaufen, bevor er gefangen wurde.

OK, gibt es sonst noch andere Variante?

Answer (score 6):

Die besten Varianten sind die bereits genannten "Ich wollte eigentlich" und "Ich hatte vor", es gibt jedoch unzählig weitere Möglichkeiten:

> Ich **war im Begriff** meine Oma zu besuchen, aber dann kam mir etwas dazwischen.
>   Ich **hatte den Plan/das Vorhaben** meine Oma zu besuchen, jedoch war mein Auto kaputt.
>   **Meine Absicht war es**, meine Oma zu besuchen, bis mir dann etwas in die Quere kam.
>   Ich **wollte das Vorhaben** meine Oma zu besuchen endlich **angehen**, als sie dann plötzlich stattdessen zu mir kam.
>   Ich **hatte den Entschluss gefasst**, meine Oma endlich zu besuchen, aber ich fand leider keine Zeit.
>   Ich **hatte den Wunsch**, meine Oma nochmals zu besuchen, doch wollte sie mich nicht sehen.
>   Ich **schickte mich an**, meine Oma zu besuchen, ...
>   Ich **war kurz davor** meine Oma zu besuchen, ...
>   Ich **war drauf un dran** meine Oma zu besuchen, ...

Auch richtig, aber abgespaced:

> Ich **gedachte** meine Oma **zu besuchen**, befand es dann aber doch zu langweilig.
>   Ich **intendierte** meine Oma **zu besuchen**, so sollte es aber nicht kommen.

Comment: Aua, wer sagt denn "intendieren"? Das klingt nach einem lieblos aus dem Englischen rübergezerrten "intend to"...

Comment: @Robert Sag das mal einem Intendanten. „Ey, dein Job ist lieblos aus dem Englischen rübergezerrt: intendant.“

Answer (score 4):

The translation is totally fine to me. If you want to introduce the contradiction you can use "eigentlich"

> Ich wollte eigentlich...

"Vorhaben" works too but you don't need the "es" here... as in you mustn't use it.

> Ich hatte vor, zu...

Of course there are other translations possible but they all are closer to

> I was about to....

To me, "wollen" is really the best option.

Answer (score 1):

> Ich **wollte**...

used most commonly

---

> Ich **hatte vor**...

this actually is usually used **for actions you are still intending to do** (in future). It indicates that you are willing to change your plans if it's reasonable

> Ich hatte vor in die Bib zu gehen - I'm going to go to the library

Using it to express the past is quite uncommon, so I skip an example.

---

> Ich **war im Begriff**...
>   Ich **war kurz davor**...
>   Ich **war drauf und dran**...

put some **more tension** in it like *gerade* would do it (*Ich wollte gerade...*).

Particularly the last two indicate, that **the intended action did not take place**, e. g.

> Ich war kurz davor die Tür zu öffnen, doch dann fiel mir ein, dass...
>   Ich war drauf und dran die Tür zu öffnen, als mir einfiel, dass...

*Ich war im Begriff...* is similar used as *Ich hatte vor...* but probably not so often.

---

> Ich **hatte den Entschluss gefasst**...

is kind of profound; one made a serious decision.

---

> **Meine Absicht war**...

usually used, when **explaining your intention** of something you did. I think more common is

> Ich **beabsichtige/beabsichtigte**...

which also has the idea of **something not trivial** (e. g. buying a house next year)

---

> Ich **wollte das Vorhaben ... angehen**

is close or even equivalent for `tackle smth`. Note that basically this is `wollte` plus another verb and usually you actually `tackled the project`.

---

> Ich **hatte den Plan/das Vorhaben**...(Plan more often than Vorhaben)
>   Ich **hatte den Wunsch**...
>   Ich **schickte mich an**...

those I do not hear that often, but totally possible