# "gerade dabei sein zu [Verb]" vs "im Begriff sein zu [Verb]" (=to be about to [verb])

Tags: verb

Gibt es eine Bedeutungsunterschied zwischen diesen Ausdrücken? Drücken sie beide dasselbe Ding aus?

> Ich war gerade dabei nach Hause zu gehen, als er ankam.
>
> Ich war im Begriff nach Hause zu gehen, als er ankam.
>
> (=I was about to leave, when he arrived)

Ich finde, dass diese Frage sich von [dieser](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9507/wie-beschreibt-man-das-futur-mit-der-vergangenheitsform) unterscheidet, weil "I was about to" ausdrückt, dass man vorhatte, etwas demnächst zu machen, hingegen "I was going to" drückt aus, dass man einfach vorhatte, etwas zu machen, aber es gibt nichts an über wann es gemacht werden wird.

Comment: Nur um dir noch ein paar mehr Varianten zu geben ... "Ich schickte mich gerade an zu..." "Ich war drauf und dran zu..." "Ich war kurz davor zu..."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Für mich haben die beiden Sätze einen Bedeutungsunterschied.

> Ich war im Begriff nach Hause zu gehen, als das Telefon klingelte.

Bedeutet: Ich wollte gerade die Arbeit beenden, Aufstehen und gehen.

> Ich war dabei, nach Hause zu gehen, als das Telefon klingelte.

Bedeutet: Das Telefon klingelte, während ich unterwegs war. Das zweite Beispiel impliziert genau genommen eine bereits begonnene Handlung, das erste nicht. Umgangssprachlich wird da allerdings wahrscheinlich oft nicht so genau unterschieden.

Answer (score 1):

Meiner Meinung nach sind die englischen Ausdrücke "I was going to do sth" und "I was about to do sth" äquivalent und bedeuten dasselbe. Beide können mit "Ich war im Begriff" übersetzt werden.

Der Ausdruck "Ich war gerade dabei" ist aber im Englischen "I was doing sth". Daher sagen die Beispielsätze etwas unterschiedliches aus und der erste Satz ist keine korrekte Übersetzung.